# Lambda Python boto3 store file in S3 bucket

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

ok, I've seen a few examples of this, and here is my code in AWS Lambda Python 3.6:

```
# I just wrote out the file before this...
import boto3
tmp = open('/tmp/' + name_str,"rb") 
s3_client = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3_client.Bucket(S3BUCKETNAME)
bucket.put_object(Key=name_str, Body=tmp, ContentType='text/csv', ContentEncoding='utf-8')
```

The error I get is :

> 's3.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'put_object':
>   AttributeError

Well, then I try:

```
s3_client.upload_file('/tmp/' + name_str, S3BUCKETNAME, name_str)
```

> 's3.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'upload_file':
>   AttributeError

So... I must be missing something basic... Is there some other import? Why can't the system find these functions?

Comment: oohhh.... incase someone wants to know... s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

Comment: You can post this as an answer for others to find the solution easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a misunderstanding of what type to use. It should have been:

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

But note that the code I actually use now is more like:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
with open('/tmp/' + name_str) as file:
    object = file.read()
    s3_client.put_object(Body=object, Bucket=S3BUCKET, Key=name_str, ContentType='whatever/something', ContentEncoding='whatever-itis', StorageClass='PICK_ONE', ACL='you_choose')
```